# Hashing text with SHA-256 at Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, utf-8, sha

```
String inputPass = textBox2.Text;
byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputPass);
byte[] inputHashedBytes = Sha256.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
String inputHash = Convert.ToBase64String(inputHashedBytes);
```

I'm getting some strange output:

> Q9nXCEhAn7RkIOVgBbBeOd5LiH7FWFtDFJ22TMLSoH8=

By output hash looks like this:

> 43d9d70828409fb46420e56005b05e38de4b887ec5585b43149db64cc2d2a07f

Comment: Define "strange output".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// This is where you get the actual binary hash
byte[] inputHashedBytes = Sha256.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

// But you want it in a string format, similar to a variety of Unix tools
string result = BitConverter.ToString(inputHashedBytes)
   // This will remove all the dashes in between each two characters
   .Replace("-", string.Empty)
   // And make it lowercase
   .ToLower();
```

Comment: Thank you! It's THE answer. :)

Answer (score 7):

`Encoding.UTF8.GetString` parses bytes as [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point).

The SHA-256 hash is an arbitrary 256-bit number and does not correspond to any Unicode text.

You probably want to show the binary value in hexadecimal, by calling `BitConverter.ToString()`. You can also call `Convert.ToBase64String()`.

Comment: It's closer, thanks. I've edited the question to show the new output - still wrong...

Comment: BitConverted worked! I need to play a little with the string thought... it's something like 43-D9 instead of 43d9