# How can I get an SHA-256 certificate thumbprint?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, sha256

How can I get the SHA-256 thumbprint of a certificate?

SHA-256 certificates have two thumbprint, and I am able to retrieve the primary thumbprint, but not SHA-256.

Comment: On Windows, the signtool program allows 2 x509 certificates to be added to a file for an authenticode hash.  The first certificate is the SHA1 certificate - for backward compatibility.  Then there is an un-authenticated attribute which has the second SHA 256 certificate.  Hence the 2 thumbprints

Comment: I want to access/read that SHA 256 thumbprint ?. Could you please help me with the Class or Property (In C#) ?.  Thank you for you reply

Comment: can you explain your task? It is unclear where you want to get SHA256 thumbprint? From certificate itself? Signed content? Else???

Comment: @CryptoGuy I want to extract the SHA 256 thumbprint from the certificate

Comment: Thumbprint. Fingerprint. [Call the whole thing off](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRrw2hDjnl4&t=25s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
public static String GetSha2Thumbprint(X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    Byte[] hashBytes;
    using (var hasher = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        hashBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(cert.RawData);
    }
    string result = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes)
        // This will remove all the dashes in between each two characters
    .Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
    return result;
}
```

After getting the Hashbytes, you have to do the bit convertion.

This post also helped me: *[Hashing text with SHA-256 in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477083/hashing-text-with-sha-256-at-windows-forms)*

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a certificate's SHA-256 thumbprint, you have to do some manual work. The built-in [Thumbprint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.thumbprint.aspx) property is [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) only.

You have to use a [SHA-256 class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx) and compute the hash over the certificate's content:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace MyNamespace {
    class MyClass {
        public static String GetSha2Thumbprint(X509Certificate2 cert) {
            Byte[] hashBytes;
            using (var hasher = new SHA256Managed()) {
                hashBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(cert.RawData);
            }
            return hashBytes.Aggregate(String.Empty, (str, hashByte) => str + hashByte.ToString("x2"));
        }
    }
}
```

And you convert this code to an extension method if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this code is not giving the correct SHA-256 thumbprint of the certificate

Comment: can you argument your statement?

Comment: Go to any website( which has https:\\) ,
 open the site in firefox , See the certificate which of the website , which shows SHA 256 thumbprint and SHA 1 thumbprint.
Using above code compare the return string and SHA 256 thumbprint which is showing in browser. This is showing different data

Comment: Please, update your initial question and put all relevant information there.

Comment: My question in starightforward , I want the SHA 256 thumbprint of any certificate .

Comment: Web browsers do not show SHA256 thumbprint anywhere. Maybe you misconfused in terminology?

Comment: I don't have FireFox browser, but I would suspect that either, Mozilla calculates SHA256 hash incorrectly or does it against different data.

Comment: The correct code is :
        public static String GetSha2Thumbprint(X509Certificate2 cert)
        {
            Byte[] hashBytes;
            using (var hasher = new SHA256Managed())
            {
                hashBytes = hasher.ComputeHash(cert.RawData);
            }
            string result = BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
            return result;
        }

Comment: Your code as well as this post helped me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477083/hashing-text-with-sha-256-at-windows-forms . Thank you @CryptoGuy

Comment: I think @Crypt32 has a good design in the original answer, but may have missed a piece of code at the end.  I don't always need absolutely copy-paste-ready code snippets in these answers to find them valuable.  If I lift code from SO I am always ready to review, test, and tweak it until it behaves, before I commit it to source control.